# i want to send an attachment in a form sql and php ..?

Tags: php, mysql

i want to send an attachment in a form so i used this code .. !

```
   <form id="form1"  name="form1" autocomplete="off" enctype="multipart/form-data"
    method="post" novalidate action="triprequestexcuton.php">
     <input type="file" name="form_data" size="40"> 
      <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
```

then in triprequestexcuton.php

```
 $form_data=$_POST['form_data'];
 $attachment = addslashes(fread(fopen($form_data, "r"), filesize($form_data)));
 $qry="insert into triprequest values('','". $attachment."');"; 
 $resultop=mysql_query($qry);
```

but one i check the database i find the fileld like this [BLOB - 0B] ! 
my problem with 0B ! 
so how can i fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contents of files uploaded with POST over *HTTP* is not stored in `$_POST`, but in another special server variable called `$_FILES`, with this said you are not doing what you're supposed to.

---

- **[PHP: POST method uploads - Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php)**